# Progress bar border overlapping rounded corner

Tags: html, css

I have a progress bar with rounded corners. When progress is 100% it overlaps the rounded corner of the background white color making it square. In Firefox it works correctly but not in the rest of the modern browsers (Chrome, Edge).

```css
body {
  background: #ccc;
}
#feedProgress {
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  border: none;
  background: #fff;
  appearance: none;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}
#feedProgress::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}
#feedProgress::-webkit-progress-value {
  background: #006DC5;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<progress id="feedProgress" value="50" max="100"></progress><br><br>

<progress id="feedProgress" value="100" max="100"></progress>
```

Comment: it's strange you used Chrome specific css selectors to style explicitely `border-top-right-radius: 0;` on `::-webkit-progress-value` but you can't see why it does exactly what you asked it to do. Firefox behaves differently because the corresponding selector would be different. You are missing that actually is Firefox misbehaving according to how you styled it

Comment: I styled it specifically for it otherwise the fill color would be rounded in Chrome. Firefox didn't need that.

Comment: yes now I got it better... You need the "value" bar to be styled straight when not filling the whole area but yet not overflow the frame having rounded borders. I admit the sarcasm went too far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `overflow: hidden` on the progress element should do the trick

```css
body {
  background: #ccc;
}
#feedProgress {
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  border: none;
  background: #fff;
  appearance: none;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  
  overflow: hidden;
}
#feedProgress::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}
#feedProgress::-webkit-progress-value {
  background: #006DC5;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<progress id="feedProgress" value="50" max="100"></progress><br><br>

<progress id="feedProgress" value="100" max="100"></progress>
```